# what am I missing in this RegEx?

Tags: javascript, regex, numbers

I'm trying to create a JavaScript Regex to test for:

a valid # between 0 and 99.9 (where only a single decimal digit is allowed)
e.g. 3.45 is not valid.

so, blank is ok, any integer between 0 and 99 is ok, and a decimal value is allowed.

I have this so far, but it is allowing values like `3.45` to pass:

```
$^|$[0-9][0-9]?^|$[0-9][0-9]?.[0-9]^
```

Comment: What's wrong with `function test(num) { return (0 <= num) && (num < 99.9) && (num*10 % 1 === 0); }`?

Comment: I would need to verify that it is a number first I know, not too hard.. `isNaN()`... otherwise that would work too.  In my specific scenario, regex testing is already built in, so pluging into it seems the easiest.

Comment: is `05.5` considered a valid response? what about `.5`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two problems I can see:

- You mixed up ^ and $.
- Your decimal point needs escaping `\.`.

Comment: doh! I would have spent all day fighting the inner matches - thanks for the head shake.

Answer (score 4):

[Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344666/what-am-i-missing-in-this-regex/3344674#3344674) already said what is wrong with your expression. Here is another way how you could write it:

```
^(\d\d?(\.\d)?)?$
```

Explanation:

- `^` matches the beginning of the string
- `(...)?` makes the whole number optional
- `$` matches the end of the string
- `\d\d?` matches either one or two digits (`?` makes the second one optional)
- `(\.\d)?` matches a dot `.` and a digit (`?` makes it optional)

Answer (score 1):

I've never really used much JavaScript, but this should do the job...

```
^[0-9][0-9]?(?:\.[0-9])?$
```

Comment: Oops, Felix Kling posted while I was typing, the two patterns are fairly similar though he took into account blank, which I didn't (missed that requirement).

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your regex as :

```
^$|^[0-9][0-9]?$|^[0-9][0-9]?\.[0-9]$
```

But better, use Felix King's one.

Answer (score 0):

Another variant is

```
/^\d{0,2}(\.\d)?$/
```

which will accept numbers like .3 if such are to be allowed.